# python django меняю значение формы и все рушится

Tags: python, django

Скачал с инета код,

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Меняю значение first name в классе и в дефе и все рушится. ошибку выдает ъ

Если не хватит информации, пишите - допишу в коммы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Customer

class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Допишите не в коммы, а отредактировав вопрос, текст ошибки. Также вы привели код модели. Форма это другое. Если вы что-то делаете именно с формой, то и её код не помешает.

Comment: @Alpensin дополнил

Comment: Под ошибкой вы сообщение на скрине имеете в виду?  В форме я вижу end name,а у модели и в форме её нет. Удалили это поле? А миграцию сделали после изменения модели?

Comment: @Alpensin Exception Value:  

table app_customer has no column named bebra_name

Comment: Сделайте миграции.

Comment: @Alpensin я их сделал, та же ошибка - table app_customer has no column named bebra_name

Comment: Какими командами сделали?

Comment: @Alpensin python manage.py migrate

Comment: Это чтобы выполнить созданные миграции. А перед этим их надо сгенерить командой python manage.py makemigrations.

Comment: @Alpensin сделал, та же ошибка

Comment: Что сделал? обе команды подряд выполнил?
Сначала python manage.py makemigrations 
Потом python manage.py migrate ?

Comment: @Alpensin Да, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Тогда ищи где в коде у customer пытаются прочитать поле с именем bebra_name , которого у него нет.

Comment: @Alpensin я все просмотрел, ничего криминального не нашел

Comment: Тогда приложи всё что там у тебя в консоли за это время, что мы переписываемся, накопилось в текст вопроса.

Comment: @Alpensin https://imgur.com/a/gtumqWl

Comment: Ладно, забей. Мой тебе совет. Сначала пройди туториал по джанге. Тут на русском https://www.djbook.ru/rel3.0/intro/tutorial01.html или на оф сайте на английском.

Comment: добавь еще код view, который обрабатывает эту форму